# Nginx - Deny access for IP address (HTTPS port 443)

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, ip-address, lets-encrypt

is it possible to block HTTPS using the IP address?

So that you cannot access my website using the IP address with HTTPS port 443.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any updates?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply! This is the default Nginx configuration that I changed: https://pastebin.com/RGxAt60J

Answer (score 1):

Found this thread on my own search for a solution. The site linked below posts a solution to reject any unconfigured ssl requests. It worked well for what I needed.

https://www.zacharyschneider.ca/2020/03/nginx-block-direct-ip-access/

Code block included for ease of access, all credit to zacharyschneider.ca for this solution.

```
server {
    listen      443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    # Disable logging
    error_log  /dev/null;
    access_log off;

    # Snakeoil TLS to appease Nginx
    ssl_certificate     /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;
    ssl_stapling        off;
    ssl_ciphers         NULL;

    # Close the connection without sending a response
    return 444;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deny all and reject connections for unknown domains, when somebody tries to use IP:80 and IP:443.

Response for HTTP(80): Connection closed without response.
Response for HTTPS(443): Reject SSL connection.

Include this config to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default_server.conf

# HTTP:80 = catch-all server block, resulting in a 444 response for unknown domains.
# HTTPS:443 = catch-all server block, resulting in reject SSL connection for unknown domains.

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name "_";
    return 444; # Connection closed without response
}

server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 default_server;
    server_name "_";
    ssl_reject_handshake on; # Reject SSL connection
}
```

Comment: Note, directive `ssl_reject_handshake` was introduced in nginx 1.19.4 at 27 Oct 2020. To upgrade nginx: `apt-get install --only-upgrade nginx`

Answer (score 0):

You can specify only a listen port in Nginx configuration.
The application will be exposed only by the Nginx listen port

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. I want to set it up so that the connection fails when you try to enter the IP address followed by HTTPS. Is that possible?

Comment: are you sepecify another port in listen port ? you should restart nginx to save change. can you put your config file ?

Answer (score 0):

Just add listen to 443 and change the server_name with your IP address, so it looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name your_ip_address;
    return 403;
}
```

Don't forget to check the syntax if it is successful or not: `sudo nginx -t`

And reload your Nginx server: `sudo systemctl reload nginx`

Comment: This gives a `nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in webapp.conf:32}`

Comment: @Phil: I'm not sure about this, maybe missing ssl_certificate? Because I installed the SSL certificate through Certbot Let's Encrypt.

Comment: @Rinaldi Pratama: yes, cert is missing. But you can't get SSL cert for IP address through Certbot Let's Encrypt. That's the problem.